# How can I get the page count of a .rtf document in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#

I found a way using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, but I can't use this solution because the machines that we are using to automate tests do not have word.

The code works on my development machine, but not where our test suite runs.  `Word.Application application = new Word.Application();` crashes the code when office is not on the machine.  Putting office on those machines isn't an option.

Can anyone help me with another solution?

.rtf by default do not have any kind of page count, when opened in WordPad for example.
As a result, I don't think I can parse the document for new page characters.  I was thinking I could try something elaborate like converting the .rtf to a .pdf or .mtiff or .jpeg file and then count the pages in the converted document (profided this method retains exactly the same page count).

However, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: That, for hopefully obvious reasons, completely depends on the paper size.  Google "c# print richtextbox" to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for a .net library that handles RTF, unfortunately this is the best I can find: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C - maybe Nuget has something for you.